# Algebraic approximation to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, approximation-theory, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have a first order differential equation of the form:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\tau}f(x,t)$

where $f(x,t)$ is a nonlinear function. In the limit where the time constant $\tau$ is small, the differential equation can be approximated by an algebraic equation. This is done by rearranging the equation.

$\tau\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t)$

ie: as $\tau \rightarrow 0$, $f(x,t) \rightarrow 0$. Physically this makes sense. How can one mathematically justify this though? Without the above manipulation, one ends up with $\frac{dx}{dt} \rightarrow \infty$. Can this somehow be equated to $f(x,t) \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: I don't know why you refer to this approximation as 'algebraic'. It could be justified, using the limit definition of the derivative, I think

Comment: I meant in the limit where an ODE becomes a simple algebraic equation. I don't know the correct mathematical for this though (or even if there is one...)

Comment: rs1223, you mean the equation $f(x,t)=0$? This is not an algebraic approximation to a differential equation, it's an approximation to its solution.

Comment: I disagree with your approach. On the opposite, we can assume that $f$ remains finite, but $dx/dt$ gets as large as you want so that $\tau dx/dt$ remains finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a counterexample, take

$$\dot x=\frac{\sqrt{xt}}\tau.$$

Then

$$2\sqrt x=\frac{2t^{3/2}}{3\tau}+C,\\
x=\left(\frac{t^{3/2}}{3\tau}+C\right)^2$$

As $\tau$ decreases, the solution increases as $\dfrac1{\tau^2}$.

Comment: Evidently the above manipulation is not valid for all f(x, t).

Comment: Yes but if you scale $t$ and $x$ appropriately this is no problem, you can write an expansion for $x$ and get good approximations.

Answer (score 1):

When you consider the equation $\tau \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} = f(x,t)$ for $\tau \to 0$, the equation is called *singularly perturbed*. These equations can be analysed using *(geometric) singular perturbation theory*, or (more generally) *multiple time scale analysis*. I highly recommend the book

C. Kuehn, *Multiple Time Scale Dynamics*, Springer, 2015

for more information on the mathematical underpinnings of techniques used to analyse this type of equations.